# PHP $argv[1] empty when called with long content

Tags: php, argv, maxlength

When I call my php program from the command line using the following command everything works fine:

```
php app.php 'TEST'
```

But using a very long argument, PHP returns an empty string for the argument:

```
php app.php 'VERY LONG ARG'
```

Any idea how to increase the max length for arguments?

Comment: @potiev this is a PHP question not a C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass strings with single quotes and spaces in them. You have to use double quotes for this, as it will count them as separate arguments.